# React stop event propagation without cancelling the event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

I have a dropdown list (or button with split) which does its thing on a click. It's inside a div which has some specific onClick behavior. How to make the click on the dropdown not being propagated to the div but also the default behaviour (opening the dropdown) not cancelled?

```
onClick = (e) => {
   e.stopPropagation();
   // continue with the original event on e.target 
   // ???
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `e.preventDefault()` ?

Comment: I actually don't need to cancel the event - so I would need the opposite: a function like e.continueDefault() instead (for the target on which the event fired, not the parent ones).

Comment: It might be useful to do e.preventDefault() on the *parent* component, but how do I know that the click came from this "muted" child? I hoped there was a straight-forward solution without refs etc (I'm new to front).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem for the moment by doing `e.stopPropagation()` on an intermediate div. So if I have div1 > div2 > div3 and I want to have onClick with default behavior on div3 but avoid it firing on div1, I just added `onClick={(e) => {e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault();}` on div2.